# Dropdownlist not recognize the regionid

Tags: c#

I have two companies:

- "Signet" has ID = 1
- "infosys" has ID = 2

These companies are related to Zones:

- "Signet": Zone="North", zone ID = 1
- "infosys": Zone="North", zone ID = 2

Each Zone has some Regions, regions can have the same names:

- "Signet": Region='kerala', region ID = 1, zone ID = 1
- "infosys": Region='kerala', region ID = 2, zone ID = 2

When I'm adding a new Territory, the Regions are not recognized properly. For example:

- the RegionID=1 is used if I select the ZoneID=1
- the RegionID=1 is used if I select the ZoneID=2
- the RegionID=2 is never user, no matter what Zone I select

Here's the code of the two related methods:

```
public string TerritoryAdd(string dropdown, string terid, string territory, string desc)
{
    string data = "0";
    string str = "select RegionID from Region where Region='" + dropdown + "'";
    SqlDataReader dr1 = conn.query(str);
    if (dr1.Read())
    {
        string id = dr1[0].ToString();
        string qry = "select Territory from Territory where Territory='" + territory+"' and RegionID='"+id+"'";
        SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(qry);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            return data = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            string qry2 = "insert into Territory values('" + id + "','" + terid + "','" + territory + "','" + desc + "')";
            conn.nonquery(qry2);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

and the data source for 'Regions' DropDown:

```
protected void fill2()
{
    string str1 = "select CompanyID from Company where CompanyName='" + ddcompany.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    SqlDataReader dr2 = conn.query(str1);
    if (dr2.Read())
    {
        string id1 = dr2[0].ToString();
        string str = "select ZoneID  from Zone where Zone='" + ddzone.SelectedItem.Text + "' and CompanyID='" + id1 + "'";
        SqlDataReader dr1 = conn.query(str);
        if (dr1.Read())
        {
            string id = dr1[0].ToString();
            string str2 = "select Region from Region where ZoneID='" + id + "'";
            SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(str2);
            dwn.dropdwnlist(str2, ddregion);
        }
    }
```

I want recognize ZoneId: 1 for "Signet" and ZoneId: 2 for "infosys".

Comment: You have large problems with both using a datareader without disposing it and SQL injection attack possibility in your code. I would advice you to rethink your approach and then rework your code first. However for your given question - debug your code and check that the values are as you expect at each step.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen i debugged program eventhough i am getting region id in my class is 1,if i select 1 or 2.

Comment: Its a bit odd to do something like `select ZoneID  from Zone where Zone=`.  It looks like you are trying to get the primary key based on some string value, what if there are multiple records with the same value in the Zone field, you are reading the first record and ignoring the rest.  DDL controls have a Value and a Text property for this purpose, the user sees the Text but you store the id in the Value which si what you use in your qeury.

Comment: I've tried really hard to make your descriptions at least somewhat readable. Please review and correct it, because I'm pretty sure not everything is like you've had on your mind - but I was unable to comprehend it better...

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I want to add territory for both company based on RegionID.I have 2 region id respectively 1 and 2.the thing is when i try to add new territory the region id 1 only recognizing if i select second zone,the region id 1 only getting 2 not getting.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, Sorry I am Not That much fluent in English..Please pardon me

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I see you've tried to change the comment a bit. Did you mean: "When I add new territory, the RegionID=1 is recognized only if I select the ZoneID=2. The RegionID=2 is never recognized, no matter what Zone I select."?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl already I told I have two Regions with same name.Now I am trying to add new territory for region 1 and region 2.I selected Region 1 from dropdownlist and add new territory its fine.And again I add new territory for region 2 but this shows error here region id 2 not recognized it recognized again id 1 and showing error "Territory already exist in the same id".

Comment: Does the REGIONs have the same name, or does the ZONEs have the same name?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl both the region and zone have same name for both companies.zone is "North" and region is "kerala"

Comment: I've added the details to your question. Please review them and correct if they are wrong.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yes,it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write :

```
ddzone.SelectedItem.Value
```

Instead of

```
 ddzone.SelectedItem.Text
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: -1: pure guess, no proof. If the app used textual descriptions of the items displayed (Text=Mom,Value=5), the queries wouldn't return "wrong values" (ID=1 all the time), but rather would return **no values** at all, or maybe even throw an exception (failed conversion). Have you considered that the autor is probably a novice, and there are no smart bindings/configurations and that the Text is displayed on defaults and is simply the same as Value (Text="5",Value=5)?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl in region if we give different data it works fine but if give same data then not working

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one of the errors lie in `fill2` method. In the middle of that method, you are SELECTing Zones and WHERE'ing over the `ZONE=..zonename..`.

This is really goot idea to do, because as you've said, you've got zones with identical names. In this case, the database will return ALL zones that have that name. You are taking the `dr1.Read..dr1[0]` which will give you only ONE of those ALL zones returned by the query. It just accidentally happens that this is all the time the same region#1. If you'd read all rows that were returned, you'd see that not only region#1, but also the other region was found too.

At the core of the problem is the fact that you are filtering the Zones over their Names. Since there are zones with the same name, you cannot rely on this. When you ask the database for "Zone named North" the database **has no way** of guessing that you mean the other North..

One of the simpler solution would be to not filter by Name, filter by ID just like Angel said (so make your query like `select ...... from Zone where ZoneID=.... and CompanyID=....`). Note the ZoneID= instead of Zone=. If you'd filter over ZoneID, there would be no ambiguity and you will always exactly get the zone you want.

However, this is not all, and as the actual problem lies elsewhere.

--

Let's see your query one more time:

```
select ZoneID
from Zone
where
       Zone='.....'
   and CompanyID='...'
```

Now, you do the filtering **not only** by the Zone's name, but also by the Company. With such query, you can safely have multiple "North" zones, one for each company:

- If you pass "North" and companyID=1, you **will get only** the "**North**" zones attached to CompanyID=1=**Signet**.
- If you pass "North" and companyID=2, you **will get only** the "**North**" zones attached to CompanyID=2=**infosys**.

If you really got one North zone attached to Signet, and the other North zone attached to infosys, there couldn't be any problems with this query.

Therefore, I think that's not what you have in the databse. I think you have in your database something like that:

- Company: Signet, ID=1
- Company: infosys, ID=2
- Zone: North, ID=1, CompanyID=1   // <-- SIGNET
- Zone: North, ID=2, CompanyID=1   // <-- SIGNET again!
- Region: Kerala, ID=1, ZoneID=1
- Region: Kerala, ID=2, ZoneID=2

instead of:

- Company: Signet, ID=1
- Company: infosys, ID=2
- Zone: North, ID=1, CompanyID=1
- Zone: North, ID=2, CompanyID=2
- Region: Kerala, ID=1, ZoneID=1
- Region: Kerala, ID=2, ZoneID=2

Please make sure that the Zones are not duplicated for each of your companies. Also, check the regions and other tables. You might have similar problems there.

I don't know how about the problems with insert-teritory. Your code in `TerritoryAdd` does not seem to use any 'zones' 'regions' or 'companies' so again you are leaving me/us/readers with guesses.

I'm terribly sorry, but my time's is up now.. maybe someone else will be able to help you more.